# JSF rich:tab switchType=ajax update first tab

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

i am using rich faces.

```
<rich:tabPanel id="feedModifyDetails" switchType="client">
     <rich:tab id="ftpDefaultValuePanel" header="FtpDefaults">
           some code
     </rich:tab>

     <rich:tab id="feedSchedule" header="FeedSchedules" >       
           some code
     </rich:tab>

     <rich:tab id="feedFTPCommunicationParams" header="FeedFTPCommunicationParams">                                                      
           some code
     </rich:tab> 

     <rich:tab id="feedFTPErrorEscalations" header="FeedFTPErrorEscalations"  
             switchType="ajax">
           <ui:include src="ftpErrorEscalations.xhtml" />
     </rich:tab>    

     <rich:tab id="ftpErrorAction" header="FtpErrorActionDefaults"  switchType="ajax">
            <ui:include src="ftpErrorAction.xhtml" />
     </rich:tab>     
 </rich:tabPanel>
```

As show in above code

1. for rich:tabPanel i am using switchType="client".
2. for last 2 rich:tab i have used switchType="ajax".

Expected Result:

1. Last two tab will be loaded when user click on tab.

Error:
When user click on any one of last tab(AJAX request tab) a ajax request is sent but response will update first tab 
i.e: `<rich:tab id="ftpDefaultValuePanel" header="FtpDefaults" >`

**Does i am doing somthing wrong?**

Comment: Can you try `immediate=true` for ajax request tab and see the results?

Comment: Thanks dude it worked... can you tell me reason behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `immediate=true` for ajax request tabs you can indicate that this component value must be converted and validated immediately (that is, 
 during Apply Request Values phase), rather than waiting until a Process Validations phase.

Comment: immediate="true" should be added to tabPanel or every tab